# How do I determine the equation to calculate the Eigenvalues of a PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Let's say I have the following boundary value problem:
$$ \partial_t u(x,t)=\partial_{xx}u(x,t)-u(x,t)+sin(\pi x),  \quad x\in(0,1),\quad t>0 $$
$$ u(0,t)=0, \quad t>0 $$
$$ u_x(1,t)=0, \quad t>0 $$
$$ u(x,t)=a, \quad x\in(0,1) $$

To find the Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors  I found the equation for this to be:
$$ \phi''(x)+\lambda\phi=0, \quad x\in (0,1) $$
$$ \phi(0)=\phi_x(1)=0 $$

However: I couldn't figure out why I have to use this equation. And how do I find the equation for other boundary-value problems? Is there a general way for this?

Comment: Was this equation simply given to you, or did you find it using separation of variables?

Comment: This equation was simply given to me. The solution just begins with this equation. Without any additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we solve the homogeneous problem using separation of variables; Let us suggest a solution of the form - $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$. Plugging this into the PDE we get:

$$T'X-TX''+TX=0$$
$$\frac{X''}{X}=\frac{T'}{T}+1$$

Since both sides of the equation depend strictly on two independent variables, we conclude that they are both equal to some constant $-\lambda$ (the minus sign is for convenience). We thus get an equation for the term that depends on $x$:
$$X''+\lambda X=0$$
Which is the equation you were given. From the given boundary conditions we know that - $$X(0)=X_x(1)=0$$
(since the result needs to be independent of the function $T$)

This explains why you need to use this equation. You can now solve the equation in order to find the part of the solution that depends on $X$. You will get a set of eigenfunctions that span the space of solutions. You can then use the temporal initial condition and the in-homogeneous part of the equation in order to find the complete solution.